# Homotopy of Involutory Matrices?

Tags: matrices, homotopy-theory, connectedness

I want to construct a homotopy from the matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

to the identity matrix within the space of involutory matrices ($A^{2} = I$). Is this even possible?

Also, how do I determine the number of path connected components of this space?

Comment: Since you're making a homotopy from one element to another... do you mean a *path*?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/480888/81360) is one way to show that this is impossible

Answer (score 7):

No such path exists. Probably the shortest proof is to observe that the trace of a matrix is a continuous function, that the trace of a matrix satisfying $A^2 = 1$ takes on a discrete set of possible values, and that it's $0$ for your matrix but $4$ for the identity matrix.

Just for fun, let's interpret the title question to ask: what is the [homotopy type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence) of the space of (real) involutory matrices? As we've seen, this space has $5$ connected components depending on the number of eigenvalues which are $1$ vs. $-1$; these can be analyzed separately. The space of involutory matrices with a given set of eigenvalues has the property that every pair of such matrices is conjugate to a diagonal matrix, hence it is acted on transitively by $\text{GL}_4(\mathbb{R})$. The stabilizer of this action depends on the eigenvalues:

- For the eigenvalues $1, 1, 1, 1$ and $-1, -1, -1, -1$ the stabilizer is $\text{GL}_4(\mathbb{R})$ and the space is a point, since scalar matrices are central.
- For the eigenvalues $1, 1, 1, -1$ and $1, -1, -1, -1$ the stabilizer is $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{R}) \times \text{GL}_1(\mathbb{R})$ and the space $\text{GL}_4(\mathbb{R})/(\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{R}) \times \text{GL}_1(\mathbb{R}))$ is diffeomorphic to the space of lines in $\mathbb{R}^4$, or equivalently the [real projective space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space) $\mathbb{RP}^3$. This is a relatively well-understood space from the point of view of homotopy theory; in particular, its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and it has universal cover the $3$-sphere $S^3$. .
- For the eigenvalues $1, 1, -1, -1$ the stabilizer is $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \times \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and the space $\text{GL}_4(\mathbb{R})/(\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \times \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}))$ is diffeomorphic to the space of planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$, or equivalently the [Grassmannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $\text{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$. This is again a relatively well-understood space from the point of view of homotopy theory; its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and it has universal cover the space of oriented $2$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$, which as it turns out is diffeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^2$. (This reflects an exceptional isomorphism and doesn't generalize.)

Comment: When you say that the set is "acted on transitively by $GL_4(\Bbb R)$", what group action are you describing, exactly?  Is it "conjugation" in the sense of $g \cdot x = gxg^{-1}$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: yes, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Let $M(t)$ be a path through the involutory matrices such that $M(0) = \text{diag}(1,-1,-1,1)$ and $M(1)$ is the identity matrix.

Let $p_t(x) = \det(xI - M(t))$, written as
$$
p_t(x) = x^4 + a_3(t)x^3 + a_2(t)x^2 + a_1(t)x + a_0(t)
$$
Clearly, $p_0(x) = (x-1)^2(x+1)^2 = x^4 - 2x^2 + 1$, while $p_1(t) = (x-1)^4$.  Note that $a_3(0) \neq a_3(1)$.

Now, note that there are finitely many possibilities for the characteristic polynomial of an involutory matrix.  However, $a_3(t)$ depends continuously on $t$.  So, $a_3(t)$ is a non-constant continuous function on $[0,1]$ that attains finitely many values.  This is a contradiction.

Thus, no such path exists.

In fact, the path components are precisely the sets of matrices with identical characteristic polynomials.  So, there will be $5$ path components in this space.

Comment: Very nice proof, the COEFFICIENTS of the characeristic poly are continuous plus there are finitely many possibilities. Nice.

Comment: Note that the minimal polynomial must divide $(x-1)(x+1)$ and so it is either $x-1$ or $x+1$ in which cases it is the identity or the negative of the identity. Or it is $(x-1)(x+1)$ in which case there are $3$ possibilities for the characteristic polynomial. So there are $5$ components $2$ of which are isolated points.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus thanks for catching that error; of course there are only $5$ possible characteristic polynomials, not $16$.  And thank you for the compliment.

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about the reals, then presumably there's no way to do this. Why? Because if $A^2 = I$, then $A$ satisfies $x^2 - 1 = 0$, whose only roots are $+1$ and $-1$. So the domain of $A$ splits as a direct sum of the $+1$ and $-1$ eigenspaces. For your matrix, these each have dimension 2; for the identity, the $+1$ eigenspace has dimension 4. Suppose you had a path $t \mapsto M(t)$ from $M(0) = A$ to $M(1) =I$. Consider $H = \{ t | M(t) \text{ has a nontrivial -1 eigenspace} \}$. Let $h$ be the least upper bound of $H$. What's the $-1$ eigenspace of $M(h)$ look like? Trivial or not? For $t< h$ you've got $-1$ as an eigenvalue twice, and for $t > h$ (at least near $h$) you've got it as an eigenvalue at most once. That seems implausible, at the very least. I'm guessing this can be converted to an actual proof.

Comment: So, I guess you're assuming that eigenspaces depend continuously on the entries of the matrix?

Comment: Not quite that; more that I was thinking about the characteristic polynomial $s \mapsto  p_t(s)$ of $M(t)$; for each $t < h$ it has roots $-1, -1, 1, 1$, and hence is a scalar multiple of $(s^2 - 1)^2$; indeed, since $p_t(0) = det (M(t)) = 1$, we know the scalar is $1$. By continuity, $\lim_{t \to h} p_t(s) = (s^2 - 1)^2$ as well. So $p_h(s) = (s^2 - 1)^2$. For $t > h$, $p_t$ is a scalar multiple of $ (s-1)^4$. That's inconsistent with continuity of the characteristic polynomial as a function of the path-parameter $t$, I believe. I should have said this instead of talking of eigenspaces, Sigh.