# Matrix is continuous function of *vector* $t$. Are its eigenvalues continuous functions of $t$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A(t)$ be a symmetrical matrix such that each element $A_{ij}(t)$ is a continuous function of a vector $t\in T\subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Are the eigenvalues of $A(t)$ continuous functions of $t$?

I found a few answers that show that this is the case when $T \subset \mathbb{R}$ (for instance [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480619/eigenvalues-of-matrix-with-entries-that-are-continuous-functions) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556137/eigenvalues-are-continuous)). Can these results be generalized to $T\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ for $m>1$?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is a continuous function of $t$.

Comment: Yes but are the zeros of a polynomial continuous in $t$ if $t$ is a vector? I suspect that they are but all the results I can find assume that $t\in T\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What does it change? The important ingredient is that the characteristic polynomial is a continuous function of matrix entries. If the matrix entries are continuous functions of whatever (scalar or vector variable), eigenvalues are continuous functions of the same whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my thought on your problem. Basically, your matrix which is a square and symmetric has elements which depend on the multi-variable vector $\mathbf{t}\in\mathbb{R}^m$. The characteristic polynomial this will generate in $\lambda$ will have coefficients which depend on your vector $\mathbf{t}$. Since finding the eigenvalues comes down to finding the roots of your polynomial there that, to me, would imply that the eigenvalues will be continuous function of $\mathbf{t}$ too. On a simple case thinking of a $2\times 2$ matrix with elements $A_{ij}(\mathbf{t})$, the polynomial would have the form

$$ \lambda^2 -Tr(\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{t}))\lambda + \det\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{t})$$

I think shows clearly that the Eigenvalues would, of course depend on $\mathbf{t}$ since the coefficient clearly depend on $\mathbf{t}$.

Comment: Yes, the eigenvalues would of course depend on $t$. But are they continuous in $t$? There are many results that show that if $t\in\mathbb{R}$ then the answer is yes. I am not aware however of a similar result when $t\in\mathbb{R}^m$ but I suspect that it is true.

Comment: I see. Yes I would suspect that you are right, I don't see any reason why they shouldn't be continuous in it as well.